# iOS - Animating background issue

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

I am trying to animate few elements on a screen, here's the code:

```
  private func setupAnimations() {

    self.emailAddress.alpha = 0
    self.fullName.alpha = 0
    self.password.alpha = 0
    self.confirmPassword.alpha = 0
    self.signUp.alpha = 0
    self.fullName.leftView?.alpha = 0
    self.emailAddress.leftView?.alpha = 0
    self.password.leftView?.alpha = 0
    self.confirmPassword.leftView?.alpha = 0

    self.emailAddress.center.x += self.view.bounds.width-10
    self.fullName.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width-10
    self.password.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width-10
    self.confirmPassword.center.x += self.view.bounds.width-10
    self.signUp.center.y += self.view.bounds.height/2

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.7, delay: 0.2, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: [.allowUserInteraction,.curveEaseInOut], animations: {

        self.emailAddress.alpha = 1
        self.emailAddress.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width-10
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: {(completed) in

        if completed {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.fullName.leftView?.alpha = 1
                self.emailAddress.leftView?.alpha = 1
                self.password.leftView?.alpha = 1
                self.confirmPassword.leftView?.alpha = 1
            })

        }

    })

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: [.allowUserInteraction,.curveEaseInOut], animations: {

        self.fullName.alpha = 1
        self.fullName.center.x += self.view.bounds.width-10
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }, completion: {(completed) in

        if completed {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                self.fullName.leftView?.alpha = 1
                self.emailAddress.leftView?.alpha = 1
                self.password.leftView?.alpha = 1
                self.confirmPassword.leftView?.alpha = 1
            })

        }

    })
```

And so on.. you get the idea - Im setting the alpha to 0 and center x to be off screen, and animate it "arriving" on the screen, its being called in viewDidLoad(). Everything worked out for a month, but recently I have checked this and here's the problem:

video link: https://streamable.com/lhqvu

The background, which is an UIImage in a superview is also being animated, making the superview (red background) being seen.

[image: screenshot of hierarchy and constraints]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try all animation in  viewDidAppear  method, separate your code of in two parts do it in view Did load 1) inital setup where you set all alpha 0 and whatever frame you are setting   2) (Do in view did appear) apply animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add your animation `setupAnimations` method in `viewWillAppear` and remove `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` from `usingSpringWithDamping` block. And in storyboard uncheck the ***safeArea*** and while setting top constraint to superview uncheck the  ***Constrain to margins*** & set zero.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to animations you should call the function on `viewDidAppear` rather than viewDidLoad.